# foreach loop is displaying the same image for all posts in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I cant seem to display the individual pictures for each post in my application. All the images are coming out the same as the last in the list. I need to convert the `Pictures` from each `post` into base64. In the controller I am trying to grab each post object and convert the Picture property to base64 then add it to `ViewBag.ImageToShow`, however `ImageToShow` can only hold one item so all my images are set to the last image in my `posts` list. If I create a `list<string>` for the `ViewBag` as one of the answers below mentioned I don't know how to index them correctly.

Model:

```
    public partial class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BlogUserEmail { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Meta { get; set; }
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Modified { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

        public virtual BlogUser BlogUser { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogUserEmail == User.Identity.Name).Include(p => p.BlogUser).Include(p => p.Category);
        foreach (var item in posts) // this is wrong 
        {
            byte[] buffer = item.Picture;
            ViewBag.ImageToShow = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }
        return View(posts.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Skip(i).Take(3))
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.Raw("data:image/jpeg;base64," + ViewBag.ImageToShow)" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
                </h3>

                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Notice in the view I am placing the `viewbag.Imagetoshow` in the foreach loop as I am creating a dynamic layout. For each image in the posts list display the image. However I cant get the viewbag to store as a list and return the correct image related to the view foreach at the same time having to convert the images to base64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of your code lies within the loop of the Index function in your controller. You are setting `ViewBag.ImageToShow` inside the loop, this variable can only hold one object thus by setting it in the loop it keeps getting reset.

You have two options here:

**Using ViewBag**

Within your controllers, create a Dictionary that holds `int, string`, ID and value respectively. Inside your loop you need to add an entry for every image that is found.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> postImages = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogUserEmail == User.Identity.Name).Include(p => p.BlogUser).Include(p => p.Category);
        foreach (var item in posts) 
        {
            byte[] buffer = item.Picture;
            postImages.Add(item.ID, Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
        }
        ViewBag.Images = postImages;
        return View(posts.ToList());
    }
```

In your View you should, before you start the loop, declare a local variable that holds the list:

```
var images = (Dictionary<int, string>)ViewBag.Images;
```

Now while in the loop you can get the desired image from the list:

```
images.Single(i => i.Key == item.ID).Value;
```

Full example as requested:

```
@{Dictionary<int, string> images = (Dictionary<int, string>)ViewBag.Images;
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Skip(i).Take(3))
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.Raw("data:image/jpeg;base64," + images.Single(image => image.Key == item.ID).Value)" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
                </h3>

                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </div>
        }
    </div>
  }
}
```

**Using a second model**

I've personally never used this before, but I've seen it done and I thought I'd just mention it.

To use this technique you have to create a second model, this model will hold your original model plus the image.

```
public class PostImageModel
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Now inside the controller we'll have to create a new List of the newly created model and fill it with the desired data:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<PostImageModel> postsWithImages = new List<PostImageModel>();
        var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogUserEmail == User.Identity.Name).Include(p => p.BlogUser).Include(p => p.Category);
        foreach (var item in posts) 
        {
            item.Picture = null;
            postsWithImages.Add(new PostImageModel()
            {
                Post = item,
                Image = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Picture)
            });
        }
        return View(postsWithImages);
    }
```

EDIT: Added so that the code will empty the byte array after its done converting it. (Thanks @Serv).

Your loop will stay the same, except instead of using `item.Title` you should now use `item.Post.Title`.

*Note that to you should now add `@model ExampleNamespace.Models.PostImageModel` on top of your View in order to use this model.*

Comment: ViewModel is the right approach, but now you are storing the image twice! Once as a byte array in the `Post` and the second time as a string in the `Image` property. This puts a lot of strain on your traffic.

Comment: Where does this go: images.Single(i => i.Key == item.Id);?

Comment: im assuming not where my old ViewBag.ImageToShow went because I already use i

Comment: I did change the i to n and put it in place however no images show with your method, I have maybe placed the var images in the wrong place.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added a example of how the view should look like.

Comment: Parser Error on the first line @{

Comment: There should be no enter/newline in between @{ and the Dictionary definition.

Comment: Awesome, don't forget the accept an answer to prevent others from responding to this.

Comment: Actually I may have to take the answer of this post as whenever I click any link now I am getting: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Post_36CB3E05FBE021D9F302EAB0DFCD761115D6457CF316217C40BCCDE715442EC8', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyBlogger.Models.Post]'.

Comment: There is no model passed in the Dictionary. Did you change anything?

Comment: no the links when ever I click on them throw this error. If i change back no error...

Comment: That's another question to be honest.. I showed you how to pass multiple items from your controller to your View. You shouldn't expect when copying my code for yours to work. Anyhow, the exception says it expected a Dictionary but obtained a Post. This is not done my code but by some other  code in your project.

Comment: Why such a complex solution? Wouldn't it be simpler to add a string property ImageToShow to the Post class and calculate it in the controller? See my answer.

Comment: That's an entity framework class, making it require the added field to be stored in the database? This means you have the image saved twice.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't notice it. I decorated the property with the NotMapped attribute, I think it's enough.

Comment: @PaoloCosta that could be working, I'm not sure about that. I'm not that familiar with EF. But after checking Google it seems that is the way to go with ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning each picture to the same ViewBag property, it's normal you always see the same one.

You should add a new string property, marked with NotMapped attribute, named ImageToShow to the model:

```
public partial class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BlogUserEmail { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Modified { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageToShow { get; set; }

    public virtual BlogUser BlogUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var posts = new List<MvcApplication2.Models.Post>();
        foreach (var item in posts) // this is wrong 
        {
            byte[] buffer = item.Picture;
            item.ImageToShow = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        }
        return View(posts.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Skip(i).Take(3))
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.Raw("data:image/jpeg;base64," + item.ImageToShow)" alt="">
                </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
            </h3>

            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are serveral ways to do this. The first and quickest would be to put all your images in a collection and then store that collection in the ViewBag. Right now, you are storing only one image in it - the last.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogUserEmail == User.Identity.Name).Include(p => p.BlogUser).Include(p => p.Category);

    // create collection
    List<string> ImageCollection = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in posts)
    {
        //add images to list
        ImmageCollection.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(item.Picture));
    }
    //Add list to ViewBag
    ViewBag.ImageToShow = ImageCollection;
    return View(posts.ToList());
}
```

Now you can access it in your view with your iterator:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.Raw("data:image/jpeg;base64," + ViewBag.ImageToShow[i])" alt="">
```

Personally, I'd create a ViewModel for this, since you don't use all properties of your `Post` class.

Create a class which wraps the properties you need. Lets call it PortfolioVM:

```
public class PortfolioVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    //not Byte[]!
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your controller we will use that ViewModel:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogUserEmail == User.Identity.Name)
                        .Include(p => p.BlogUser)
                        .Include(p => p.Category)
                        .Select(vm => new PortfolioVM(){
                            Id = vm.Id,
                            UrlSlug = vm.UrlSlug,
                            Picture = Convert.ToBase64String(vm.Picture),
                            ShortDescription = vm.ShortDescprition
                         }) ;

    return View(posts);
}
```

Now we need to change your view, to use that new ViewModel. Change the first line where model is declared to:

```
//insert correct namespace!
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Subfolder.PortfolioVM)
```

After this you can display your image like every other property of your view:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Skip(i).Take(3))
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.Raw("data:image/jpeg;base64," + item.Picture)" alt="">
            </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
            </h3>

            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { urlslug = item.UrlSlug }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Now its showing the first image instead of the last.

Comment: Don't use the ViewBag. It's really tricky to get it right with your nested loops in the view. Use the ViewModel. If you want to layout your items in rows with 3 items, i'd suggest you use a js library like Masonry for this.

Comment: Why not a byte? My database table is of type varbinary(max) the EF model automatically creates a byte array.

Comment: Because you are displaying it as a string in your view, don't you? Storing it as a byte[] wouldn't make sense

Answer (score -3):

You are doing it wrong! you store all images in the same variable!

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogUserEmail == User.Identity.Name).Include(p => p.BlogUser).Include(p => p.Category);

        // this is what you should do, or something like this
        ViewBag.ImagesToShow = new List<String>();

    foreach (var item in posts)
    {
        byte[] buffer = item.Picture;

        // this is really wrong!
        //ViewBag.ImageToShow = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

        ViewBag.ImagesToShow.Add(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
    }
    return View(posts.ToList());
}
```

and you have also need to change your view

Comment: You are assigning the property on each iteration too! same mistake.

Comment: You're re-assigning the ViewBag property on each iteration. You should move the initialization outside of the loop.

Comment: The output looks like this: src="data:image/jpeg;base64,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: @GarrithGraham Well, obviously you will need to fetch the correct index from the `ImagesToShow` list.